# How to Return a Promise Request Within Another Request?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, promise, request

Q: I understand how to return a promise within a ***request***, but how do I return a new promise in a ***request inside another request***?

---

**My code:**

```
request({ // --------------request 1------------
    url: request_data.url,
    method: request_data.method,
    form: request_data.data,
    headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data, token))
}, function (err, res, body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < body.items.length; i++) {
        if (body.items[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(params.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            ids[count] = body.items[i].id;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        request({  **request 2** ------------request 2--------------
            url: request_data2.url,
            method: request_data2.method,
            form: request_data2.data,
            headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data2, token))
        }, function (err2, res2, body2) {
            body2 = JSON.parse(body2);
            var counts = 0;
            var ret = {};
            //console.log(ids[0]);
            for (var i = 0; i < body2.items.length; i++) {
                //console.log(body2.items[i].name);
                for (var y = 0; y < body2.items[i].custom_attributes.length; y++) {
                    if (body2.items[i].custom_attributes[y].attribute_code == 'category_ids') {
                        if (ids[0] == body2.items[i].custom_attributes[y].value) {
                            ret[counts] = body2.items[i].name;
                            counts++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } //------- resolve / reject ----------
            if (err) {
                reject({
                    statusCode: 500,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                });
            } else {
                resolve({
                    body: JSON.parse(ret),
                })
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I had only one request, the output worked. But when there is another request within a request, I receive an **empty output {}** when I try to invoke this function.

Comment: Promises were introduced to prevent callback hell and flatten a hierarchy of callbacks . You're not really using them. I'd suggest to switch to `request-promise` for starters, this will help to keep things straight.

Comment: still not sure how to use request-promise within 2 requests though

Comment: Promises are supposed to be chained with `then`. You can use async..await to make this even easier.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, stop doing things in non-promise callbacks. You shouldn't do anything "within a request" other than to resolve a promise:

```
function requestAsync(data, headers) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url: data.url,
            method: data.method,
            form: data.data,
            headers,
        }, function (err, res, body) {
            if (err) reject(err); // don't ignore errors!
            else resolve(body);
        });
    });
}
```

Now, you can put your business code in the `then` callback, and from `then` callbacks you can also `return` other promises to make a chain:

```
const oauthHeaders = oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data, token);
return requestAsync(request_data, oauthHeaders).then(JSON.parse).then(body => { /*
^^^^^^ */
    const ids = [];
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < body.items.length; i++) {
        if (body.items[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(params.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            ids[count] = body.items[i].id;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return requestAsync(request_data2, oauthHeaders).then(JSON.parse).then(body2 => {
//  ^^^^^^
        var counts = 0;
        var ret = {};
        //console.log(ids[0]);
        for (var i = 0; i < body2.items.length; i++) {
            //console.log(body2.items[i].name);
            for (var y = 0; y < body2.items[i].custom_attributes.length; y++) {
                if (body2.items[i].custom_attributes[y].attribute_code == 'category_ids') {
                    if (ids[0] == body2.items[i].custom_attributes[y].value) {
                        ret[counts] = body2.items[i].name;
                        counts++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return {
//      ^^^^^^
            body: JSON.stringify(ret), // I don't think you meant `parse` here
        };
    });
}).catch(err => {
    return { // I don't think you want to `throw` this object
        statusCode: 500,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    };
});
```